# Probability for a uniform distribution: mean and varience

Tags: probability, statistics

I am stuck on a question and don't know how the textbook got the answer. Please help: "The random variable $X$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, find the mean and variance of the variable $P:=4(1-X^2)^{0.5}$ ". They got the answer for the mean as $\pi$, please explain how??

Comment: We can do it without explicit integration, because $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ is the integral for the area of a quarter-circle of radius $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, let $X$ be a random variable with density function $f_X(x)$, and let $Y=g(X)$. Then the mean of $Y$ is given by
$$E(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f_X(x)\,dx.$$
In our case, $f_X(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$, and $0$ elsewhere, and $g(x)=4\sqrt{1-x^2}$.
We can evaluate the integral by noting that $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ is the integral for the area of a quarter circle of radius $1$.

For the variance of $P$, use the fact that $\text{Var}(W)=E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$. We already know that $E(P)=\pi$.

To find $E(P^2)$, use the fact that $P^2=16(1-X^2)$. Thus
$$E(P^2)=\int_0^1 16(1-x^2)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

p(x) = 1 (the pdf, because it's constant and the length of the region is $1$, therefore $\int_0^1 dx = 1$ gives the proper overall probability of $1$), therefore the mean is simply:

$$
[P] = \int\limits_0^1 P(x)dx = 4\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2}dx
$$

Do you really want to take the integral?  It requires a trig-substitution, otherwise, you can just consult a table of integrals, or better yet, [Wolfram](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=sqrt%281+-+x%5E2%29&random=false):

$$
\int \sqrt{1 - x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sin^{-1}(x)\right) + C
$$

Now just evaluate from $0$ to $1$:

$$
4\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2}dx = 2\left.\left(x\sqrt{1 - x^2} + \sin^{-1}(x)\right)\right|_0^1 = 2\left(\sin^{-1}(1) - \sin^{-1}(0)\right)
$$

$\sin(0) = 0$ therefore $\sin^{-1}(0) = 0$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$ so $\sin^{-1}(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  So the integral is just $2\frac{\pi}{2} = \pi$

Comment: Better than Wolfram, tables, substitutions etc: $\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ is the area of a quarter circle with radius $1$.

Comment: @Jared +1 vote. Nice answer.

Comment: Sorry why do i not have to integrate 4x(1-x^2)^0.5 as i thought this was how you got the mean?? why is it different in this case

Comment: @user135842 you should have a look at first two chapters of your text book.

Comment: This was in the first and was the first question!

Comment: @David yes that is definitely the best way (totally forgot about that).