# Probability density function help

Tags: probability, statistics

If a random variable is given by $Y=aX+b$ where $X$ is a random variable does that mean $aX+b$ is $Y$'s pdf?? and if i wanted to find $E[Y^2]$ would this just be the same as finding $E[(aX+b)^2]$ and if so why is it not the case that if $X=f(x)$ $E[X]=E[f(x)^2]$ but $= \int(x^2f(x))dx$ ?? please help

Comment: Wow... Which textbook are you following, exactly?

Comment: OCR MEI S4 (a level)

Comment: What is $f(x)$ when you write $X=f(x)$? If $f(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$, then such notation makes no sense.

Comment: This is an exam, not a textbook, no? So... which textbook?

Comment: This is the name of the text book i think it is published by ocr

Comment: And it seems you simply grasped nothing of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/729950), for example. Then why accept it?

Comment: "This is the name of the text book" Ah? OK. And how do they define PDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things in your question: [random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variables), [probability density functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

If $X$ is a random variable, then $aX+b$ is also a random variable and you can calculate the expected value of $Y$ using the [properties of expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties):
$$
\operatorname E(aX+b)^2=\operatorname E[a^2X^2+2abX+b^2]=a^2\operatorname EX^2+2ab\operatorname EX+b^2.
$$
But $aX+b$ is not $Y$'s probability density function. In fact, $Y$ might not even have a probability density function at all. Only continuous random variables have probability density functions and we do not know whether $Y$ is a continous random variable.

The law of the unconscious statistician helps us find an expected value of a random variable $Y$ given by $g(X)$ with a measurable function $g$ without explicitly knowing the distribution of $Y$. We only need to know the distribution of $X$.

So when we calculate
$$
\operatorname EX^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)\mathrm dx
$$
for a continuous random variable $X$, we are actually using the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: If Y was a continuous random variable would aX+B be its pdf or something like af(x)+b ???

Comment: @user135842 No, $aX+b$ would not be its pdf. $aX+b$ is another random variable, not even a pdf. If $X$ is a continuous random variable, then so is $Y$, but it is not that straightforward to find the pdf of $Y$. You can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables) how we can find the pdf of $Y$